# Can I make alt-tab window always appear on the primary screen in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, alt-tab

Right now it appears on whatever screen the app I'm switching from is located. If I while alt-tabbing I accidentally stop on my radio player, located on my alt screen, it's most annoying.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the window manager or desktop environment.

Comment: @Gilles - added gnome tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not having my Alt-Tab window on my primary screen was a huge annoyance for me when I had two monitors.  When I noticed my Alt-Tab window had wandered over to the wrong screen, I would invoke this Python script with a keyboard shortcut:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -E
import gtk 
gtk.gdk.display_get_default().warp_pointer(gtk.gdk.screen_get_default(), 800, 600)
gtk.gdk.flush ()
```

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python all it does is act like you have clicked on your primary screen.  This is a kludge, sure, and doesn't fix the root issue, but it's the best workaround I could come up with at the time.